# Gitlab CI/CD .gitlab-ci.yml file invalid on spaces in strings?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, cicd

This is pretty bizarre.

I opened file `.gitlab-ci.yml` in Gitlab's Pipeline Editor.

When I have double-quoted string without spaces in the file it's OK:

[image]

Note no space between `PRIVATE-TOKEN:` and `$EXAMPLE_TOKEN`.

Pipeline Editor says " Pipeline syntax is correct." and all is fine, I can run the pipeline on commit etc.

However, when I enter a space there the editor complains:

[image]

At the top the editor displays message:

"This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: jobs:build_appliance:after_script config should be a string or a nested array of strings up to 10 levels deep."

Trying to run the pipeline on commit fails with messages about invalid YAML. The strange thing is I checked this string in an online [YAML validator](https://www.yamllint.com) and it says it's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue even I face when I use curl with "`--`" options. The Gitlab yaml parser gets thrown off by this "`--`".

Here is how you can work around this. Please note the "`|`" at the begining of your `after_script`, with which you can avoid both adding a "-" on each line of your script and also this solves the nested string error message.

You can use "|" similarly in `before_script` and `script` as well.

sample after script with dummy echo just to show mutiple lines of script

```
after_script: |
  echo "I dont have to use "-" on each line os script section anymore"
  curl --globoff --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "<your gitlab api url>"
  echo "more lines..."
```